# Seeking a more efficient manner for Ordering before Grouping, with Unions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

The following code works for what I am looking for but I am trying to see if there is a better way to create an efficient news feed. This news feed is supposed to choose the most recent comments and/or likes, etc but only exhibit the most recent per user (i.e. if John liked 2 items and commented on 3 items, only show the most recent comment and like. Please note that there are multiple UNIONs involved.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT username, time, comment FROM comments ORDER BY time DESC) AS temp 
GROUP by username 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT username, time, likes FROM likes ORDER BY time DESC) AS temp 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can `JOIN` the two tables on `username`, but this will give you extra columns instead of the union, something like:

```
SELECT
  c1.username,
  c1.`time` AS CommentTime,
  c1.comment,
  l1.`time` AS LikeTime,
  l1.likes
FROM comments AS c1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT username, MAX(`time`) LatestTime
   FROM Comments 
   GROUP BY username
) AS c2  ON c1.username = c2.username
        AND c1.`time`   = c2.LatestTime
INNER JOIN Likes l1 ON c1.username = l2.username
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT username, MAX(`time`) LatestTime
   FROM Likes
   GROUP BY username   
) AS l2  ON l1.username = l2.username
        AND l1.`time`   = l2.latestTime
ORDER BY c1.`time` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This will give you the `username` with the latest comment and the latest `likes` with the latest time.